# How to integrate Croatian Language pack for my magento site?

Tags: magento-1.9, language, magento-connect, language-package

I have just installed yestheme for magento and customizing it. But now i have a issue for Croatian Language install in magento, i searched for pack but whenever i tried to install it.

[image]

And this is Croatian Language for for magento, i tried to install.
[image]

And the error showing on magento connect manager:
[image]

I would like to install Croatian Language pack, so looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can download language pack from here.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140710093357/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/34

After extract this file copy app folder and paste in your magento root folder. clear cache and check out.

Happy Coding. :)